# Requesting help for a type of control

Tags: vb.net

I want to add a control in winforms that drops like combo box but can show data like datagridview.  I have seen this control in an application but not able to find a way how to do it. (Pic attached)

Thanks[image]

Comment: you can try infragistics control..

Comment: Could u explain bit further, what is that control

Answer (score 0):

You can "emulate" it by showing a form without borders containing a DataGridView when user clics on that cell.